# Audit access to files in file systems

Tags: java, windows, unix

Is there a way to know if a file in the file system was read/put in the clipboard?

I'm using java and I'm thinking about this approach for a question I've posted previously.
[Lock a file for reading even from Operating System except a single process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547224/lock-a-file-for-reading-even-from-operating-system-except-a-single-process)

I don't have a specific technology, but I would like to solve this problematic with Java.

Comment: You've tagged windows and unix - which is it?

Comment: My preference is towards windows, but like I've said, I'm open to suggestions even from other operating systems.